# NextJS Middleware causing "localhost redirected you too many times" error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, middleware, next-auth

I just implemented email/password authentication into my locally hosted NextJS app with NextAuth. When I created the middleware to protect routes, whenever I clicked the sign out button, I got the error "localhost redirected you too many times."
[image: Image of the error]

This is my `middleware.ts` file:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const path = req.nextUrl.pathname;

    const session = await getToken({
        req,
        secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    });
    if (!session) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', req.url))
    } else if (session && (path === '/login' || path === '/signup')) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', req.url))
    }
    return NextResponse.next()
}
```

Is there a way to protect all routes like this without middleware or make function without redirects?
TYA

Comment: I think when you redirect to the login page, your session is still empty hence it redirects you to the login page again.

Comment: Maybe you should add another guard to check if you're already not on the login page. So check if the session is empty and you're not on the login page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect from middleware in next.js 13 AppDir: true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882100/redirect-from-middleware-in-next-js-13-appdir-true)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It occurs because you wrote an if with only a condition (!session), then always redirected to the same route (/login) causing too many redirects to the same route.

To solve the problem change the if to `!session && path !== "/login"`

Comment: with this guard condition my problem is now solved. thanks for that. but now I'm facing another new problem after redirecting `/login` route and that is: my application layout is going to break down I think that is happening because when I redirect `/login` during this time my root CSS chunk is not loaded yet so can you help me what should I do now

Answer (score 2):

There will be an evident solution but I think it's also good to check if you have additional routing settings. In my case /api and /_next directories are always redirected to '/'.

```
export const config = {
  // Skip all paths that should not be internationalized. This example skips the
  // folders "api", "_next" and all files with an extension (e.g. favicon.ico)
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next|.*\\..*).*)']
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this - had to do something like this to protect every page outside of `/login`.

Answer (score 0):

adding config under the middleware function. solved my issue.

```
export const config = {
    matcher: [
        '/',
        '/login'
    ]
}
```

because the pathname was constantly changing. so it went inside the "if" condition even if isLoggedIn = true and pathname== '/login'

Answer (score -1):

Just check only auth in middleware. No need to check for the other routes. Other routes will managed by next accordingly.

```
const session = await getToken({
    req,
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
});
if (!session) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', req.url))
```

}