# Redirect from middleware in next.js 13 AppDir: true

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I am trying to make a redirect when I don't get the jwt back-end. I am in next.js 13 with the `appdir` active.

middleware.ts

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const token = req.cookies.get('token')
  if (!token) {
    return NextResponse.redirect('/login')
  }
  return NextResponse.next()
}
```

Comment: can you first make sure your middleware is running? add a `console.log("middleware is running")` inside middeware

Comment: If it is printing the token in console but when I put the redirect it gives error

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: `error - node_modules\next\dist\server\web\utils.js (94:0) @ Object.validateURL
error - URL is malformed "/login". Please use only absolute URLs - https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-relative-urls
null`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', req.url))
```

Looks like it needs absolute url

You should not run this middleware when user visits “login” page.

```
const pathname = req.nextUrl.pathname
```

Check pathname in login page, according to it if “pathname===“login” do call “next”. Do not run the middleware for the `login` page. Because `login` page should not be protected

Comment: works but it keeps looping because it starts to check if the user is logged in.

Comment: You have to exlude logjn route. Because what is happening is when you visit login page same middleware runs again