# Next auth middleware redirect infinite loop

Tags: next.js, middleware, next-auth

I use middleware to redirect unauthenticated users to my custom sign in page. But I get an infinite loop of redirects to the default sign in page provided by next auth.

My middleware.ts file looks like this:

`export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";`

My auth options look like this:

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  callbacks: {
    jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      console.log(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser);
      return token;
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
  },
  providers: [
    DiscordProvider({
      clientId: env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    /**
     * ...add more providers here.
     *
     * Most other providers require a bit more work than the Discord provider. For example, the
     * GitHub provider requires you to add the `refresh_token_expires_in` field to the Account
     * model. Refer to the NextAuth.js docs for the provider you want to use. Example:
     *
     * @see https://next-auth.js.org/providers/github
     */
  ],
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect from middleware in next.js 13 AppDir: true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882100/redirect-from-middleware-in-next-js-13-appdir-true)

Comment: See this related NextAuth issue: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/6979